# Updating metadata on Picasa using Google Data API for Java

Tags: android, picasa, google-api-java-client

I'm using [Google Data API](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/) to connect Picasa from Android. To retrieve the pictures and the metadata it works great, but I get an IllegalArgumentException on parsing the response of an PATCH (relative to original). The header is "text/html" although the ouput of the parseAsString-method delivers a perfect xml-string. Is that a bug or do I need to create my own Parser for "text/html"?

I also wouldn't mind updating with the PUT-method, does anyone have a good example how to do that with Java?

Here the exception:

```
Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No parser defined for Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
 at com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponse.parseAs(HttpResponse.java:277)
 at com.unimelb.pt3.external.google.api.Entry.executePatchRelativeToOriginal(Entry.java:95)
 at com.unimelb.pt3.external.google.api.PhotoEntry.executePatchRelativeToOriginal(PhotoEntry.java:67)
 at com.unimelb.pt3.Picasa.updatePicture(Picasa.java:135)
 at com.unimelb.pt3.Tools.updatePictureOnPicasa(Tools.java:209)
 at com.unimelb.pt3.ui.WaterfallView.onDraw(WaterfallView.java:145)
 at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6535)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1531)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1258)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1529)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1258)
 at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6538)
 at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1531)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1258)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1529)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1258)
 at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6538)
 at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
 at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:1830)
 at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1349)
 at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1114)
 at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1633)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here the code in the Entry:

```
Entry executePatchRelativeToOriginal(HttpTransport transport, Entry original)
  throws IOException {
      HttpRequest request = transport.buildPatchRequest();
      request.setUrl(getEditLink());
      request.headers.ifMatch = etag;
      AtomPatchRelativeToOriginalContent content =
          new AtomPatchRelativeToOriginalContent();
      content.namespaceDictionary = Util.NAMESPACE_DICTIONARY;
      content.originalEntry = original;
      content.patchedEntry = this;
      request.content = content;
      Log.i(Prototype.TAG, request.url.toString());
      HttpResponse response = request.execute();
      // Log.i(Prototype.TAG, response.parseAsString());
      return response.parseAs(getClass());
}
```

Here the relevant code from the main Activity:

```
public void updatePicture(String url, String description, String[] tags) throws IOException {
    PhotoEntry photo = photos.get(url);
    PhotoEntry patched = photo.clone();
    patched.summary = description;
    String keywords = "";
    for(int i=0; i<tags.length; i++) {
        keywords += tags[i] + ((i==tags.length-1) ? "" : ", ");
    }
    patched.mediaGroup.keywords = keywords;
    photo = patched.executePatchRelativeToOriginal(transport, photo);
}

private HttpTransport setUpTransport() {
    HttpTransport transport = GoogleTransport.create();
    GoogleHeaders headers = (GoogleHeaders) transport.defaultHeaders;
    headers.setApplicationName("google-picasaatomsample-1.0");
    headers.gdataVersion = "2";
    AtomParser parser = new AtomParser();
    parser.namespaceDictionary = Util.NAMESPACE_DICTIONARY;
    transport.addParser(parser);
    return transport;
}
```

**EDIT:**
I added to the setUpTransport method the following lines:

```
   XmlHttpParser p2 = new XmlHttpParser();
   p2.contentType = "text/html";
   p2.namespaceDictionary = Util.NAMESPACE_DICTIONARY;
   transport.addParser(p2);
```

That leads to another IllegalArgumentException with that log:

```
 Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: expected start of XML element, but got something else (event type 4)
     at com.google.api.client.xml.Xml.parseElementInternal(Xml.java:180)
     at com.google.api.client.xml.Xml.parseElement(Xml.java:152)
     at com.google.api.client.xml.XmlHttpParser.parse(XmlHttpParser.java:73)
     at com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponse.parseAs(HttpResponse.java:280)
     at com.unimelb.pt3.external.google.api.Entry.executePatchRelativeToOriginal(Entry.java:95)
     at com.unimelb.pt3.external.google.api.PhotoEntry.executePatchRelativeToOriginal(PhotoEntry.java:67)
     at com.unimelb.pt3.Picasa.updatePicture(Picasa.java:130)
     at com.unimelb.pt3.Tools.updatePictureOnPicasa(Tools.java:209)
     at com.unimelb.pt3.ui.WaterfallView.onDraw(WaterfallView.java:145)
     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6535)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1531)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:158)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1529)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1258)
     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6538)
     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1531)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1258)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1529)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1258)
     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6538)
     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:1830)
     at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1349)
     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1114)
     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1633)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Is this bug removed from google-api or does it still persist. I am facing the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [XmlHttpParser](http://javadoc.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/1.2.1-alpha/com/google/api/client/xml/XmlHttpParser.html) and set its [content type](http://javadoc.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/1.2.1-alpha/com/google/api/client/xml/XmlHttpParser.html#contentType) to "text/html".

By the way, in response to a PATCH, Picasa Data API should be returning content type "application/xml", not "text/html".  So that's possibly a bug.

EDIT: I haven't investigated this myself, but I suspect this IllegalArgumentException is because the text/html content is not well-formed XML content.  We don't actually have an HTML parser.  I wonder though why you feel you need to parse the HTML response, given that parseAsString gives you what you need.  By the way, Picasa Data API shouldn't be returning an HTML response, so that's probably a bug on their end (not that there's anything you can do about other than file a bug report).

Disclaimer: I'm an owner of the [google-api-java-client](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client) project.

Comment: I added in setUpTransport() the following line:

Comment: I guess its better to put it at the bottom of the question ^^

Comment: Please show what response.parseAsString() and request.url.toString() look like.  That might be useful hints.